# Cross-platform C# (Xamarin) - Execute Tasks while "Asleep" on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

We're writing a cross-platform C# "Xamarin" application; right now we're just targeting the iPad.  The application has two features relevant to this question:

1. The app requires that the user authenticate to the app (in addition to logging onto the iPad)
2. The app connects to a remote device over Bluetooth

So the question becomes, what happens when the user switches to another app, which results in our app's OnSleep() being called.  In OnSleep() we could immediately disconnect Bluetooth and log out the user, but that seems like poor usability, especially if they are just quickly checking some alarm that triggered or an instant message that came in.

For the sake of usability, we're thinking to have a 1-minute timeout; if the user does in fact pop out and quickly pop back into the app, we'd like things to simply continue on without any loss of communication or re-authentication.

If, in OnSleep(), I set up a timer using Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(), that timer does not fire while the app is "asleep".

What does it take to have a small background task/thread/process execute, even while the app is asleep?  Something that simply waits 1 minute, and then shuts down the Bluetooth communication and sets a flag indicating re-authentication is needed?

Comment: refer to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/ios_backgrounding_techniques/